# Turkey.gov.tr libpkcs11wrapper.so Ubuntu Generic thing

Tags: java, jre

While trying to access https://www.turkiye.gov.tr/ using smart identity cards, browser Java Application whether if you have libpkcs11wrapper.so file on your library.

General thing is when you search on web you will find as "install libpkcs11wrapper.so to /usr/lib/ dir" but this does not solves the problem.

But this doesn't fix the problem.

Comment: We would appreciate questions and answer separate from eachother so the best answer can be accepted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To solve problem you have to copy `libpkcs11wrapper.so` to your compatible Java version's lib directory.

For Ubuntu 14.04 and Oracle's Java 8 lib directory is

```
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/amd64/
```

not

```
/usr/lib
```